# Getting HystrixRuntimeException: Function timed-out and fallback failed

Tags: java, hystrix

I am using hystrix 1.5.3 and running this piece of code in my local machine.

```
@HystrixCommand (groupKey = "BookService", commandKey = "BookService.BookDetail", commandProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty (name = EXECUTION_ISOLATION_STRATEGY, value = "THREAD"),
            @HystrixProperty (name = CIRCUIT_BREAKER_ENABLED, value = "true"),
            @HystrixProperty (name = EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_ENABLED, value = "true"),
            @HystrixProperty (name = EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS, value = "1500")}, threadPoolProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty (name = CORE_SIZE, value = "60"),
            @HystrixProperty (name = MAX_QUEUE_SIZE, value = "60"),
            @HystrixProperty (name = QUEUE_SIZE_REJECTION_THRESHOLD, value = "60"),
            @HystrixProperty (name = KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_MINUTES, value = "1")
    })
    public String getBookDetail(String bookId)
    {
       log.info("Getting details");
       ...
    }
```

On our servers it works fine however I get this runtime exception on my local machine. My local server just waits for the timeout duration and in the end throws this HystrixRuntimeException. Also, I don't have any fallback defined but it should not be needed for my case. The expectation is it should work normally like in our production server.

```
com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: BookService.BookDetail timed-out and fallback failed.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$21.call(AbstractCommand.java:793) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$21.call(AbstractCommand.java:768) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:77) ~[rxjava-1.0.12.jar:1.0.12]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.12.jar:1.0.12]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.12.jar:1.0.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1448) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1373) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.12.jar:1.0.12]
```

I checked the function is not being executed as the log is not getting printed.
When I change the timeout by modifying `EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS` similar behaviour happens just after the new timeout duration.
When I remove the @HystrixCommand annotation it just works fine so it means there is some issue with Hystrix only. The hystrix properties seem is the one which is defined in the annotation which seem fine. Could this be because hystrix is not configured properly? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not being executed in 1500ms.

Change EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_ENABLED to false, hystrix will not timeout your method.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this also fails when running in debug-mode. Probably because the timeout is so low.

For me, it's a Spring project, the issue was that the commandKey (in this case `BookService.BookDetail`) was not defined in the `application.properties` file. 123 value below is a placeholder for any number:

```
hystrix.command.BookService.BookDetail.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=123
hystrix.command.BookService.BookDetail.circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage=123
hystrix.command.BookService.BookDetail.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold=123
hystrix.BookService.BookDetail.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds=123
```

Seems like OP was trying to define these using `@HystrixProperty` instead of a `application.properties` file. Maybe there's a typo in the property names.